# An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 76743200-1017657 (1358022652)

Tags: apex, soql, map, dynamic-soql, gack

Using the below code, I get this error message:

> An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 76743200-1017657 (1358022652)

```
String sql = 'SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType =Case';
Map<Id,RecordType> caseMap = new Map<Id, RecordType>([sql]);
```

I am from Java background I know below works fine, but why not above ?

```
Map<Id,RecordType> caseMap = new Map<Id, RecordType>([SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Case']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap any string literal in quotes. When using a dynamic query, you must also escape them.

```
'... WHERE SObjectType = \'Case\''
// missing:              ^^    ^^
```

Or you could also rewrite that as:

```
String caseType = '\'Case\'';
// wrap in quotes!    ^^    ^^

String soql = 'SELECT DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObectType = ' + caseType;
```

Or better yet, use merge variables:

```
String sObjectType = 'Case';
String soql = 'SELECT DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = :caseType';
```

As written, your current query would be the same as:

```
SELECT DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = Case
```

This query is obviously invalid. As stated above, the filter value needs to be wrapped in single quotes (as you do in the static version you include in the question).

---

A couple asides:

1. The query language is named SOQL, not SQL.
2. You should always favor static queries over dynamic when they are viable.
3. When merging in strings provided by a user, make sure you escape single quotes to avoid injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: I tried that this also doesn't works. It says unexpected sql.
`String str = 'Case';
String sql = 'SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType='+str;
Map<Id,RecordType> caseRTMap = new Map<Id, RecordType>([sql]);`

Comment: @MattW You didn't try what I recommended, what you did is completely different and just replicates the error...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the appropriate method if you choose to use a string for your SOQL. The following (almost) works:

```
String sql = 'SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType =Case';
Map<Id,RecordType> caseMap = new Map<Id, RecordType>(Database.query(sql));
```

As pointed out by Adrian, you need to use quotes when a String is expected:

```
String sql = 'SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType =\'Case\'';
```

The `[query]` notation only works for literal queries:

```
Map<Id,RecordType> caseMap = new Map<Id, RecordType>([
    SELECT DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Case'
]);
```